# Why can't I perform software updates? (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)

Tags: 16.04, dpkg, update-manager

I am a new linux user, I've only been using linux for about three months. Recently, I noticed that whenever my software updater prompted me to update, after it tried to update the new software it would give an error message telling me the operation failed. I've tried using the command line to fix the solution, but whatever I try I repeatedly get these error messages:

```
~$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease             
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease        
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76-dev/stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease     
Reading package lists... Done                      
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kbd : Depends: console-setup but it is not installed or
                console-setup-mini but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Or:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  console-setup
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  console-setup
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 156 not upgraded.
15 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/118 kB of archives.
After this operation, 447 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
Setting up util-linux (2.27.1-6ubuntu3.4) ...
insserv: warning: script 'K01vpnagentd_init' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'vpnagentd_init' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and urandom if started
insserv:  loop involving service urandom at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service hwclock at depth 3
insserv: There is a loop between service vpnagentd_init and udev if started
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop at service plymouth if started
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop at service vpnagentd_init if started
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv:  loop involving service mountkernfs at depth 1
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service vpnagentd_init and dns-clean if started
insserv:  loop involving service dns-clean at depth 1
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package util-linux (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 util-linux
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I would really appreciate any insight into this problem!

Comment: Please look at: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/289667/unable-to-install-anything-using-apt-get-because-of-insserv

Comment: So I checked out the posted link, and I looked at the cups-browsed file in /etc/init.d, but everything seemed fine. That being said I'm not entirely confident I know what I'm looking at.  The parts of the cups-browsed file that post said to check seem fine:

`#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          cups-browsed
# Required-Start:    $syslog $remote_fs $network $named $time
# Required-Stop:     $syslog $remote_fs $network $named $time
# Should-Start:      avahi-daemon
# Should-Stop:       avahi-daemon
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6`

Comment: Then did you purge?

Comment: @George Udosen I'm trying to figure this out as I go, I'm not sure what I should be purging,  but the files mentioned, K01vpnagentd_init and vpnagentd_init, are missing LSB tags and overrides. The files are supposed to help manage my  Cisco vpn client. Are these files causing the Loop in dependencies, or are they obsolete scripts? Also, should I be purging these files? I can post the files if helpful

Answer (score 0):

@George Udosen Thank you for the help. After looking at the link, I was looking at the file that was causing the problem: 'vpnagentd_init'. The file was software from when I installed Cisco anyConnect, and was missing the LSB tags. After running the cisco uninstall file, fixing some configuration problems, and running sudo apt-get install -f, I was able to fix the Software Updater.